# После быстрого поочередного нажатия по кнопкам для перехода на ViewController, вызов dismiss срабатывает только для одной ViewController

Tags: swift

столкнулся с такой проблемой:

Есть ViewController **A**, в которой есть возможность перейти при помощи двух кнопок на ViewController **B** и **C**. 
**A** соединен в storyboard с **B** и **С** Custom переходом. Если в работающем приложении быстро успеть нажать на обе кнопки, происходит переход на **B** и **C**. Так вот, если вызвать в одном из двух `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` то срабатывает это только в первом **A**, и попадаем на ViewController **B** после нажатии кнопки "Назад" во ViewController **B** окно не закрывается. Как сделать так чтобы срабатывало всегда и в обоих?

Comment: Как насчет того, чтобы при нажатии на одну кнопку отключать действие другой и наоборот.?

Comment: Это можно сделать, нет проблем. Но почему так и есть ли решение другим способом. Почему вдруг ViewController перестает закрываться?

Comment: сложно сказать не видя кода. Если предоставите тестовый проект, то посмотрю